# Creating a Watson Studio Project with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm doing the IBM professional data science certificate and one of the tutorials is making a jupyter notbeook in watson.

The tutorial says to click "Add to project"  which brings up a menu of asset types, one of which is notebook.  However, this is not an option when I do it.

Anyone know why this may be the case?

Answer (score 0):

This is the assets menu I get. Please confirm you have the same options. Which options are missing for you? If you have a javascript blocker, please try disabling it. [image: Assets menu in IBM Watson studio]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are 14 asset alternatives for adding to your project, among which "Notebook" is the 5th one.

I am not sure, but I suspect that the reason why you can't see that option is related to the region where you created your Watson instance. Maybe some features are not enabled in some regions.